# How to change MTU setting permanently?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, mtu

I need to permanently change `MTU` to `1500`. By permanently I mean if I reboot the system or if I do `service network restart` it should always be `1500`.

I followed this article http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-redhat-fedora-debian-linux-mtu-size/

But unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Here is what I did:

check current `MTU` :

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
```

Added `MTU="1500"` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`:

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xxx~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
USERCTL=yes
PEERDNS=yes
IPV6INIT=no
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=yes
IPV6_MTU="1500"
MTU="1500"
```

Then check `MTU` again, ( no luck ):

```
root@ip-xx-xx-xxx ~]# service network restart 
Shutting down interface eth0:                              [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  
Determining IP information for eth0... done.
                                                           [  OK  ]
[root@ip-xx-xx-xxx ~]# ip addr show eth0 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
```

`/sbin/ifconfig` changed `MTU` but only temporally

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xxx ~]# /sbin/ifconfig eth0 mtu 1500 up
[root@ip-xx-xx-xxx ~]# ip addr show eth0 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
```

If i restart `network` it is 9001 again:

```
[root@ip-xx-xx-xxx ~]# service network restart 
Shutting down interface eth0:                              [  OK  ]
Shutting down loopback interface:                          [  OK  ]
Bringing up loopback interface:                            [  OK  ]
Bringing up interface eth0:  
Determining IP information for eth0... done.
                                                           [  OK  ]
[root@ip-10-0-1-135 ~]# ip addr show eth0 
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

the MTU in your enviroment is being set automatically via the DHCP, in your configuration you have this setting:

`DEVICE=eth0`

`BOOTPROTO=dhcp`

So the DHCP is actually setting the MTU size. In Ubuntu, you can edit the following file: `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

Just BEFORE the request line set this two commands:

`default interface-mtu 1500;`

`supercede interface-mtu 1500;`

I don't know how to set it in Red Hat, but I think the file is called `dhcpd.conf`

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you mean "supersede" in "s" instead of "supercede" in "c"?

Answer (score 0):

If dhclient.conf doesn't exist in your OS, all settings about dhclient.conf wouldn't work. Please refer to: https://github.com/linux-enhancement/set_mtu.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).